# Accordion Javascript plus sign doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I am doing an accordion in JavaScipt, in my HTML I have two separate divs for questions title and separate div for "+" sign. My goal is when I click on div with class accordionTitle I want "+" sign change to "-" and at the same time show the answer. I am pretty new to development, what the best approach here? Can you help me?

HTML:

```
<section class="qnaSection">
    <h1 class="qnaTitle">FAQ</h1>
    <div id="qnaContainer" class="qnaContainer"></div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.qnaSection {
  background-color: rgb(35, 57, 94);
  color: var(--brown);
}

.qnaTitle {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.qnaContainer {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.accordionItem {
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
  color: black;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  
}

.accordionItemTitle {
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 3.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordionItemPush {
  /* content: '\002B'; */
  font-size: 2rem;
  /* position: absolute;
  right: 1rem; */
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  min-width: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.accordionItemPush.active::after {
  /* content: '\2212';  */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.accordionContent {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accordionParagraph {
  padding: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent,  rgb(101, 101, 136), transparent) 1 ;
  transition: max-heigth 0.2s ease-out;
}

.accordionItem.active + .accordionContent {
  max-height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
const questions = [] // array with questions
const qnaContainer = document.getElementById("qnaContainer")

const generateTitleHtml = title => {
    return `
      <h3>${title}</h3>
    `
}

const generateQuestionHtml = item => {
  return `
  <div class="accordionItem">
    <div class="accordionItemTitle">
      <p>${item.question}</p>
      <div class="accordionItemPush">
        +
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordionContent">
      <p class="accordionParagraph">${item.answer}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  `
}

const listQ = questions => {
  qnaContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', generateTitleHtml(questions.title))
    questions.items.forEach( question => {
      qnaContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', generateQuestionHtml(question))
    })
}

listQ(questions.regularQuestions)
listQ(questions.membershipBilling)

const accordionItemHeaders = document.querySelectorAll(".accordionItemTitle");


const toggleBar = () => {
  accordionItemHeaders.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener("click", () => {
      checkCurrentlyActiveItem(item)
      toggleActive(item)
    })
  });
}

const checkCurrentlyActiveItem = (accordionItemHeader) => {
  const currentlyActiveItem = document.querySelector(".accordionItemTitle.active");
  if(currentlyActiveItem && currentlyActiveItem!==accordionItemHeader) {
      currentlyActiveItem.classList.toggle("active");
      currentlyActiveItem.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = 0;
  }
}

const toggleActive = (accordionItemHeader, itemBtn) => {
  accordionItemHeader.classList.toggle("active");
  const accordionItemBody = accordionItemHeader.nextElementSibling;
  if(accordionItemHeader.classList.contains("active")) {
    accordionItemBody.style.maxHeight = accordionItemBody.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
  else {
    accordionItemBody.style.maxHeight = 0;
  }
}

toggleBar()
```

Comment: Check you console. There's an error in your JS.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is: instead of putting the HTML code in the javascript, create elements with `document.createElement("elementName")` and then set its class name or id. Then you can set an onclick-event on the element and change its innerText or innerHTML to a "-". I think [this](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/dom/manipulating/create-a-dom-element/) link can be useful. If you have any questions, ask them :)